# how ActiveX can be updated automatically at client machine

Tags: activex, setup-deployment

I have created an ActiveX control which is installed in the client machine. Now I have made some changes in the ActiveX control and now want that Changed ActiveX should be updated in the client machine automatically.

I have changed the version of the setup file from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 and "removePreviousVersion" to "True" but still it is not asking for update.

Should i change the AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion of the assmeblyinfo.cs file.

Am I missing something to change the product code or update code or version?

Comment: Have you increased the version number of ActiveX update? It is important for the OS to detect that it is different from current installation.

Answer (score 1):

"asking for update" must be your implementation. ActiveX/COM-s do not update automatically. You can run Setup to preinstall the new version.

However you can implement some service/background process which checks for new version via internet. There must be web/file server connected to internet which shares some small file (e.g. text or XML saying which is the latest available version).